# Asphalt (petroleum product) vs cement (carbon emitter) -- how to choose?

Tags: greenhouse-gas-emissions, construction, cement

[This answer](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/10513/3379) to another question points out that asphalt, a petroleum product, is used in large quantities. If we as a society want to reduce our dependence on fossil fuels, we will need to find an alternative.

The main alternative which comes to mind is cement. However, in 2016, [cement production was responsible for 3% of global CO<sub>2</sub> emissions](https://ourworldindata.org/emissions-by-sector#direct-industrial-processes-5-2).

When choosing between a carbon emitter and a petroleum product, it seems like it would be very important to have all the facts. **Is there an LCA comparing the two?** Long-term, what product should we be using to construct our roads?

Some related questions:

- [Most promising decarbonisation routes for clinker, cement and concrete?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/most-promising-decarbonisation-routes-for-clinker-cement-and-concrete)
- [Can Asphalt and concrete be recycled at long term?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6673/can-asphalt-and-concrete-be-recycled-at-long-term)
- [Concrete vs asphalt: which is better in terms of sustainability?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4948/concrete-vs-asphalt-which-is-better-in-terms-of-sustainability)

This last question addresses different applications of the products, and which may be appropriate depending on requirements. In this case, I'm interested in comparing them in cases where either product would be generally suitable.